# What do I replace bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_app_system.append with in a blender script so that it will work in 3.3.1?

Tags: python, blender

I downloaded an add-on for blender to change all the keybinds to dvorak since that's what I use. It is supposed to show up in the menu when you click the icon and go under settings. However it seems they changed how you put that there since the script was written and now it gives me an error because bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_app_system.append doesn't exist. I just want to put the menu options back where they are supposed to go but I can't find that on blenders site so I figured I'd ask yall.

I've tried just outright deleting the one line that it doesn't like and that ended up with the add-on running but the menu option is nowhere to be found. I've tried searching through docs.blender.org but that doesn't seem too intuitive when I don't know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Python_API section Breaking Changes they say to replace it with bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_blender_system .